# Can we trust a password manager mobile application?

Tags: password-management, android, ios

I personally have a lot of accounts on the internet each containing a different and difficult password to remember. Also Pins for ATM cards. So I normally forget these or try to put wrong one. I thought of using a password manager application but is it secure to use a password manager mobile application ? (ios/Android) How can we trust an application with all this sensitive information?

I am learning ios development, So should I create my own app to store my passwords and bank account details or I can trust any application on the store ?

Comment: You already trust a mobile app with all your sensitive data - it's the browser. You enter all kinds of passwords and card numbers in there. A password manager will be no different and while it's a single point of failure it's still better than weak or reused passwords.

Comment: why wouldn't you? Do you trust password manager PC applications? Do you trust online services or extensions like LastPass or whatever? If so, what make you think Android or iOS are different?

Comment: No, I have not used any password manager yet, That;s why i am asking

Comment: @UmairAfzal then your question is rather, "can we trust a password manager?" which has been discussed here before. For example, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/password-manager-vs-remembering-passwords